# how to display - 03d 01h 10m in php?

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I am using timestamps and need to print the date in the format `03d 01h 10m`. I could not do it using the `date()` formatting. How can I do it so that after the days I have a `d`, after the hours `m`, and after the minutes `m`?

Comment: What have you done so far?  Post the code that you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

Just escape the literal characters you want with a backslash:

```
date('\h\e\l\l\o'); // just echoes hello
```

If you escape a character that didn't need escaping, it doesn't matter - nothing bad worth noting happens.

Answer (score 3):

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php): Example #2 Escaping characters in date():

```
<?php
// prints something like: Wednesday the 15th
echo date('l \t\h\e jS');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this: `echo date ("d\d. H\h. i\m.");`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the DateTime class' `diff` method. See the examples [over on php.net](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).